# 20.04 headless on Raspberry pi 4 re-install will not allow password authentication on ssh

Tags: ssh, password, authentication, raspberrypi, headless

I installed 20.04 on a new headless pi 4 - no problems.

Using Raspberry Pi Imager and selecting 20.04 server each time.

Decided to re-install for a clean production environment but the new installation will not allow password authentication for ssh.

Previously clean installation accepted ssh ubuntu@ipaddress asked for pw: ubuntu = all good

New installation, Putty reports: "fatal error" "No supported Authentication methods available [server sent: publickey]

I checked user-data file "ssh_pwauth: true" =ok

I tried including a public key I generated (I have zero experience at this.

```
users:
- default
- name: jda
    gecos: John Arundell
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: users, admin
    lock_passwd: true
    passwd: ********
    ssh_authorized_keys:
        - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC etc.
```

no good - I'm on about my fifth iteration - next step is to go buy a micro HDMI to HDMI and plug in

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is:
do not edit the user-config file as suggested because, no doubt, you will follow the examples and/or the cloud-init 'readthedocumentation' and then it will not work.

Why?

Because the YAML parser will not deal with the space in ': ' required by cloud-init for the ssh_pwauth: yes thereby causing the server to default to non-password authentication.

It only took me 2 days. I just hope I save someone else the time.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 20.04.3 the first line of `user-data` must be:

```
#cloud-config
```

otherwise the whole file gets ignored.

Comment: I am sharing this with the hope somebody will not waste hours on a headless installation, like I just did